# Infinitely many primes of the form $4n+3$ proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

So I have seen this proof plastered everywhere, and here is a version of it from my textbook. No matter where I read, I don't understand one step of the proof, and I will highlight below. It surely has something to do with the Lemma that states for $x=y+z$, if $a\mid y$ and $a \mid z$, then $a\mid x$. Thank you.

> Fact: There are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+3,$ where $n$
> is a positive integer.

**Proof:** Let us assume that there are only a finite number of primes of the
form $4n+3,$ say $p_0=3,p_1,p_2,...,p_r$.
Let $$Q = 4p_1p_2\cdot\cdot\cdot p_r+3.$$
Then, there is at least one prime in the factorization of $Q$ of the form $4n + 3$.
Otherwise, all of these primes would be of the form $4n + 1$, and by Lemma
2.6, this would imply that $Q$ would also be of this form, which is a
contradiction. However, none of the primes $p_0,p_1,...p_n$ divides $Q$. The
prime $3$ does not divide $Q$, for if $3|Q$, then $3|(Q-3)=4p_1p_2...p_r,$ *(How did they reach this? I don't understand why $3$ does not divide $4p_1p_2...!$ )*
which is a contradiction.

Likewise, none of the primes $p_j$ can divide $Q$,
because $p_j|Q$ implies $p_j|Q-(4p_1p_2...p_r)=3$ which is absurd. Hence,
there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n + 3$.

Comment: If 3 divides 4p1p2...pr, then at least one must be divided by 3 but p1,...,pr>3 as defined. Consider tha 4=2 times 2. And 2 2 p1p2...pr are just prime factorization of this number. And this factorization must be unique. So 3 must be in it.

Comment: The construction omits $p_0 = 3$.

Comment: @stephenkk Could it be said that p_1,...p_r can't be divisible by 3 because they are all prime? I'm not sure I quite understand the logicafter 4=2*2. Thanks

Comment: For any number n greater than 1, there are unique sequence of primes p0,...,pr, such that n=p0p1...pr. So if 3 is a prime dividng n, then it must be that one of p0...pr must be 3 since 3 is also a prime.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a rearrangement ( or alteration) of that lemma : $$x=y+z\implies x-y=z\land x-z=y$$

So we get by factoring out that: $$a\mid x \land a\mid y \implies a\mid z$$ and $$a\mid x \land a\mid z\implies a\mid y$$

This is equivalent to $$a\nmid x \land a\mid y\implies a\nmid z$$ and $$a\nmid x \land a\mid z\implies a\nmid y$$

Answer (score 0):

I prefer   saying the primes in the list are $4n-1,$  then defining

$$Q = 4p_1p_2\cdot\cdot\cdot p_r-1.$$